# $SPWeb.GetList - Exception

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list using PowerShell, so I am executing this code:

```
 $list = $web.GetList($web.Url +"lists/TestList")
```

It's giving me:

> Exception calling "GetList" with "1" argument(s):
>   "0x80070002" At line:1
>   char:1
>   + $list= $web.GetList($web.Url +"lists/TestList")
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

How do I get a list by its Title, if I run this:

```
$list = $web.Lists | ? {$_.Title -eq "TestList"}
```

Wouldn't this loop through all lists in the site which will be bad for performance?  Thanks for any hint to guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Can you supply the values you are returning.  What is in $web.url?  If you run an output of all your lists and their URL's is /testlist returned?  It's possibly using something different maybe test%20Lists, or something else?

Comment: The returned value from $web.lists + "/lists/TestList" is : http://server1:9999/sites/finance/lists/testlist .. but it's giving an error stated above. My list doesn't have spaces between the letters.

Answer (score 5):

Inspect the result of your request string

```
 $list = $web.GetList($web.Url +"lists/TestList")
```

my guess is that you get something like https://weburllists/testlist  - try adding the leading slash in your query.

```
$list = $web.GetList($web.Url +"/lists/TestList")
```

Another way is to use the Lists method.

```
$list = $web.Lists["listname"]
```

Comment: I tried this, gave me same error..

Answer (score 4):

I believe GetList method requires server relative url as a parameter. Please check [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29495/spweb-getlist-cannot-complete-this-action) for details. You can try to use web.ServerRelativeUrl instead of web.Url but getting list by title is also not a bad idea.

```
$list = $web.Lists["ListTitle"]
```

It will enumerate all lists on your site, but it's pretty fast and you can ignore this little impact in a script.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
 $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Title of list")
```

This will never throw an error, but `$list` will be null if no list with that title is found in the web

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what I do is make use of the `Measure-Command`

```
Measure-Command {
$list = $web.Lists | ? {$_.Title -eq "TestList"}
}
```

Specifying an itemid, url, and such is always better than a where clause.

Comment: But aren't you using a where clause here?

Comment: yes, but it just measure's the time/efficiency of the command instead. The point of `Measure-Command` is to measure the efficiency of whatever command is in the block, so you can choose one or the other. It's only meant for testing.

Answer (score 0):

For googlers searching for "Get-SPWeb GetList MethodInvokationException":

In my case we had a script that used

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Site $url
```

Here, the root web and all subwebs of the site collection will be returned and stored in the `$web` variable - which is equivalent to the C# version

```
using (var site = new SPSite(url))
using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
{ ... }
```

to get the SPSite's root web **if and only if** the site collection contains only the root web. But loading a list via `$web.GetList("foo")` where `$web` is actually a collection of `SPWeb`s fails with a `MethodInvokationException`.

So you might want to check if your site collection contains subwebs.